# Excepciones en una clase

Tags: python

Voy a reutilizar este ejercicio que hice para crear una o varias excepciones donde vea si al introducir los datos de clientes vea si son validos o no, es decir, si la id es numérica y nombre y apellido una cadena de caracteres.
He estado leyendo sobre las excepciones pero no he visto ejemplos donde se hagan excepciones en los contructores de clase o en la clase en si. Podriais ayudarme. Gracias de antemano.

```
class Cliente(object):
    def __init__(self, id, nombre, apellido):
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "ID:{}, Nombre:{}, Apellido:{}" .format(self.id, self.nombre, self.apellido)


print(Cliente(2323, "Paco, "Pelaez"))
```

Comment: Y sii se lo pones al print??

Comment: tan solo compara el tipo de dato y si no es el que quieres genera una excepción, por ejemplo `if type(id)!=int: raise ValueError`

Comment: Las excepciones se usan para manejar casos **excepcionales**. Las validaciones son parte de la lógica del negocio, algo normal, no excepcional.

Answer (score 1):

Los métodos de una clase, incluyendo `__init__` pueden generar excepciones como cualquier otro método o función.

En este ejemplo definimos una clase `Persona` con tres atributos: nombre, fecha de nacimiento y sexo. Validaremos simplemente que vengan esos tres valores (que sean distintos de `None`). Si no es el caso, generamos una excepción.

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, nac, sexo):
        if nombre is None or nac is None or sexo is None:
            raise ValueError("Faltan parametros", 10)
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.nac = nac
        self.sexo = sexo
```

Para generar la excepción usamos `raise` con el constructor de una excepción adecuada. En este caso usamos `ValueError`, ya que es la que mejor representa el problema:

> exception ValueError
>
> Se genera cuando una operación o función recibe un argumento que tiene el tipo correcto pero un valor inapropiado, y la situación no se
> describe con una excepción más precisa como IndexError.

La lista completa la tienes en [Lista de Exceptiones de Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/exceptions.html)

#### Atrapar la excepción

Siguiendo con el ejemplo, cuando declaras una persona

```
try:
    persona = Persona("Raul", "01/10/2001", "m")
except ValueError as err:
    print(err.args)
```

tienes que rodear la declaración con un `try-except` y procesar consecuentemente la excepción.

En este ejemplo, simplemente imprimimos los argumentos usandos en el `raise`. Estos vienen como una tupla en el atributo `args` de la excepción, y los puedo usar para comunicar cualquier info de interés desde el constructor (texto y código del error entre otros).

Demo

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, nac, sexo):
        if nombre is None or nac is None or sexo is None:
            raise ValueError("Faltan parametros", 10)
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.nac = nac
        self.sexo = sexo


try:
    persona1 = Persona("Jorge", "01/10/2000", "m")
    persona2 = Persona("Raul", "01/10/2001", None)
except ValueError as err:
    print(err.args)
```

produce:

```
('Faltan parametros', 10)

Process finished with exit code 0
```